# House groaning and 'tock'ing like a ship at sea

Tags: wood, noise

About a half-hour ago, I heard a deep groaning noise, like the timbers of an old wooden ship at sea make.  That lasted the space of several seconds.  Half a minute or so after that stopped, I heard a deep 'tock-tock-tock' sound (definitely not some sort of bug ticking), which also sounded like ship's timbers.  I went to check on the other side of the wall, but it was quieting and I could barely hear anything before it stopped completely.

Is something going on with the wooden frame of my house?  I know houses make odd noises all the time, but this house was built in 1999 and I bought it 9 years ago and it has *never* made noises like this before now, even during wind storms with gusts above 90mph.  I should also note that I live on the Washington coast where it is nearly always damp and wet, though we did have a very dry summer and the rains started in earnest about a month ago.

Comment: Has any work been done on the house recently?  Do you see any new cracks in walls or ceilings?  Have any floors moved out of level?

Comment: Also have there been any major storms in your area lately?

Comment: possibly an earthquake ?

Comment: In Florida, I would worry about a sinkhole. For Washington state, I'd go with the mild earth shifts. Perhaps you can contact a local seismologist and ask if anything registered about the time you experienced your haunting.